# Pandas create new dataframe based off of earliest created time for each indicator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns.  One for the `indicator` one for when it was `created` and one for the `source` that reported the indicator.  I am looking to create a new dataframe(df2) with just the rows of the earliest time that the `indicator` was reported aka the `created` time.

```
 df 
    indicator      created                   source
 0  110.52.29.165  2019-01-17T12:39:23.640Z  source1
 1  110.52.29.165  2018-10-11T13:58:58.125Z  source2
 2  110.52.29.165  2019-01-12T06:45:51.252Z  source3
 3  99.25.26.33    2019-03-08T12:40:22.116Z  source2
 4  99.25.26.33    2019-01-08T01:20:55.152Z  source3
 5  59.99.52.13    2018-05-22T12:12:52.116Z  source1
 6  59.99.52.13    2019-02-04T13:51:53.147Z  source2
 7  125.25.26.6    2019-01-11T11:22:13.132Z  source3
 8  125.25.26.6    2018-10-12T12:51:22.222Z  source4
 9  125.25.26.6    2018-11-26T08:09:44.147Z  source2
10  125.25.26.6    2019-02-10T22:28:29.138Z  source5
11  129.92.22.12   2019-03-01T21:21:11.115Z  source2
```

Format:

```
>>> type(df.indicator.iloc[0]
<class 'str'>
>>> type(df.created.iloc[0])
<class 'str'>
>>> type(df.source.iloc[0])
<class 'str'>
```

The final dataframe would look like the following:

```
df2
   indicator      created                   source
0  110.52.29.165  2018-10-11T13:58:58.125Z  source2
1  99.25.26.33    2019-01-08T01:20:55.152Z  source3
2  59.99.52.13    2018-05-22T12:12:52.116Z  source1
3  125.25.26.6    2018-10-12T12:51:22.222Z  source4
4  129.92.22.12   2019-03-01T21:21:11.115Z  source2
```

Comment: does the order of the final dataframe matter?

Comment: Try with drop_duplicates , like `df.sort_values('created').drop_duplicates(['indicator'],keep='last')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if this is what you want:

```
df.sort_values("created").groupby("indicator", as_index=False).first()

    indicator       created                     source
0   110.52.29.165   2018-10-11T13:58:58.125Z    source2
1   125.25.26.6     2018-10-12T12:51:22.222Z    source4
2   129.92.22.12    2019-03-01T21:21:11.115Z    source2
3   59.99.52.13     2018-05-22T12:12:52.116Z    source1
4   99.25.26.33     2019-01-08T01:20:55.152Z    source3
```

**Timings**

```
%%timeit
df.sort_values("created").groupby("indicator", as_index=False).first()
4.67 ms ± 97.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit # @Wen-Ben 
df.sort_values('created').drop_duplicates(['indicator'],keep='first')
2.31 ms ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```